# give tableviewcell buttons different colors according to index. this did not work neither in WilldisplayCellAt nor at the CellForROwAt level

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

**This code works fine ONLY when i sroll through my table view but the first cell that loads and appear are not taking the needed colors. I tried to call the func in CellforRowAt and CellWillDisplayAt and both had the same effect**

**And what is driving me crazy is that the backgroundview takes the colors correctly, But the Button title color only takes effect for the first cells upon scrolling and the code of view and button are implemented in same func**

The class extensions where i load my cell from a XIB file

extension MyPlansTableViewCellPresenter : UITableViewDataSource {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyPlansTableViewCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let newcell = cell as! MyPlansTableViewCell
    newcell.setCellColors(index: indexPath.row)
    //This code works fine ONLY when i sroll through my table view but the first cell that loads and appear are not taking the needed colors. 
}
}
```

My cell is designed in a XIB file and loaded there and here is the Class of it

```
class MyPlansTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var renewBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var upgradePlanBtn: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}


public func setCellColors(index: Int){
    if index % 2 == 0 {
        upgradePlanBtn.titleLabel?.textColor = .TextColor
        holderView.backgroundColor = .TextColor
    } else if index % 2 == 1 {
        upgradePlanBtn.titleLabel?.textColor = .systemYellow
        holderView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
    }
}
```

[image: This is what i want to achieve, My codes works well only after scrolling but to overcome the first cells that appear on launch]

Comment: what is holderView? I did not see any variable with that name in MyPlansTableViewCell

Comment: Holderview is the one that is changing blue and yellow, Sorry i try to commit as much code as possible and show the needed one, so holder view is loading and functioning correctly but the text ib button of the first three cells that loads immedialtely does not function properly only after scrolling all workd good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this !!

```
public func setCellColors(index: Int){
if index % 2 == 0 {
    upgradePlanBtn.setTitleColor(.TextColor, for: .normal)
    holderView.backgroundColor = .TextColor
} else if index % 2 == 1 {
    upgradePlanBtn.setTitleColor(.systemYellow, for: .normal)
    holderView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
}
```

You have to specify the state of the button in the code using this code

```
upgradePlanBtn.setTitleColor(.systemYellow, for: .normal)
```

Comment: This worked thank you, but what is the special thing in this that made it work, am just curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you set color inside draw function

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: But this will be added in my XIB file, and i need to load cells according to their index, its not fixed

Comment: add index as a property inside cell and set in cellforrow